# How do you adjust the window decoration size on a QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering how you adjust the size (particularly height) of the window decoration on a QMainWindow. I want behaviour similar to the QtDesigner, Xcode and Skype. I tried adding a QToolBar with the following code:

```
QMainWindow *mainWindow = new QMainWindow();
QToolBar *bar = new QToolBar();
bar->setFixedHeight(100);
bar->setFloatable(false);
bar->setMovable(false);
mainWindow->addToolBar(bar);

mainWindow->show();
```

Compared to what I want it is still a long way off - :
[image: On the left you can see what I want and on the right you can see what I currently have]
On the left you can see what I want and on the right you can see what I currently have.

Is this possible in Qt? If yes, how would this effect be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was simple. All I had to do is call:

`mainWindow->setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true);`

Problem solved!

---

Edit, 2013-08-19:

It appears that as of Qt5, you need to pull this [git repository](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmacextras) and build the library - then link it to your project. In order to set the unified title and toolbar, see the provided examples in the repository.